# Como puedo obtener los datos en tiempo real con angular y firestore?

Tags: angular, firebase, servicio, get, real-time

Quería hacer una consulta, cuando elimino un producto no lo elimina en tiempo real solo cuando actualizo el navegador, lo mismo cuando creo un producto.

Comment: Qué error te da con la parte de `snapshotchanges`? ¿Puedes ponerlo también? El problema en este caso, ¿es que no se actualiza la lista a tiempo real?

Comment: claro no se actualiza en tiempo real. el error : core.js:6228 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined.y tambien me pone la propiedad docs no existe en el tipo documentChangueAction , supuestamente tengo que cambiar el get por snapshotchanges. –

Comment: añade el error a la pregunta para mejorar la calidad. Podrás pulsar el botón de editar y añadir el error. Gracias!!

Comment: ahi añadi el error a la pregunta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema esta en el uso de get(), al hacer esto los valores te los traerá una sola vez, en cambio es mejor usar **valueChanges** con esta te devolverá si los datos han sido cambiados

Ejemplo:

```js
data={
uid = 'pepe'
}


 function getTest(){
 
  return this.db.collection('users', ref =>   ref.where('uid', '==', data.uid))
      .valueChanges()
      }
```

un saludo :)

Comment: Bueno ahora el código funciona si agrego un producto pero no lo elimina..no se si es el lugar correcto.     
         
         
       this._firestore.collection(this.colProduct).stateChanges().subscribe((collection) => {
          collection.forEach( d => {
          const data:any =  d.payload.doc.data();
          data.id = d.payload.doc.id;
          this.products.push(data);

Answer (score 0):

Voy a tratar de darte una respuesta aproximada:

Por un lado, sé que en Firebase `Javascript SDK` (ahora mismo no he encontrado el igual en `TypeScript`) existe [el método `on`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Query#on).

Con él, a partir de una referencia, se puede detectar un [evento de `firebase database`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database#eventtype).

Lo que no tengo claro es si se puede hacer igual para los [eventos de firebase-realtime](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/realtime-database#event_types).

En todo caso, supongo que si con algo similar al [`value event`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#value-event).

> **value event**
>
> Este evento se disparará una vez con los datos iniciales almacenados en esta
>   ubicación, y luego se disparará nuevamente cada vez que cambien los datos.

```
var ref = firebase.database().ref("Producto");
//observa que pongo el tipo de evento con la ruta completa por orientarte 
ref.orderByKey().on("value",    function(snapshot) {
    //Aquí ya tratas el snapshot como quieras.  
    //Seguramente con un forEach para   modificar el objeto directamente.
});
```

También tienes otros eventos como child-added o child-removed, o los de [firebase-realtime](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/realtime-database#event_types). Yo he pensado inicialmente en `providers/google.firebase.database/eventTypes/ref.update`. Si te fijas en el espacio de nombres, es firebase.database igualmente, así que parece que puede utilizarse quizá con el método `on`, aunque esto es mi suposición.

Comment: No sé el que no sale!! ;)

Comment: Bueno ahora puedo agregar un producto, pero no lo elimina.